# Firefox CSS Placeholder Issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, placeholder

I am trying to animate the my input placeholders. As it is, it works in Chrome, but I'm having trouble with the firefox implementation.

Here is my SCSS:

```
input[placeholder], :-moz-placeholder, ::-moz-placeholder {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

  &[style*=hidden] {
    color: $gold;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
}
```